# Docusign - eSignature REST API Update method does not remove tab items

Tags: docusignapi

when I create a template using the Rest API everything looks great however if I try to use update  API providing the templateId to remove tabItems the tabItems are still present. Does update only add and edit and not delete? It would be nice to be able to add and remove items from an existing template as opposed to creating/deleting all the time.

Initial Create followed by Update request

```
  "requestBody": {
    "data": {
      "attributes": {
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "roleName": "PrimaryInvestor",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "routingOrder": "1",
              "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                  {
                    "locked": true,
                    "xPosition": "379",
                    "tabLabel": "test1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "width": "20",
                    "required": false,
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "yPosition": "120"
                  },
                  {
                    "locked": true,
                    "xPosition": "379",
                    "tabLabel": "test2",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "width": "20",
                    "required": false,
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "yPosition": "140"
                  },
                  {
                    "locked": true,
                    "xPosition": "379",
                    "tabLabel": "test3",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "width": "20",
                    "required": false,
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "yPosition": "160"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "documents": [
          {
            "fileName": "non-prod/localhost/templates/bc1e82ca-978b-4c45-9e08-bf78d62e7408/sF4UIknZTQysIFUKd0sO_1pgPDF.pdf",
            "order": "1",
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Hi there doc name",
            "bucket": "wfh-longterm-filestore-non-prod"
          }
        ],
        "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {
          "name": "delete test",
          "description": "asdfasdf",
          "folderName": "Altigo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "requestBody": {
    "data": {
      "attributes": {
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "roleName": "PrimaryInvestor",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "routingOrder": "1",
              "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                  {
                    "locked": true,
                    "xPosition": "379",
                    "tabLabel": "test1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "width": "20",
                    "required": false,
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "yPosition": "120"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "documents": [
          {
            "fileName": "non-prod/localhost/templates/bc1e82ca-978b-4c45-9e08-bf78d62e7408/sF4UIknZTQysIFUKd0sO_1pgPDF.pdf",
            "order": "1",
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Hi there doc name",
            "bucket": "wfh-longterm-filestore-non-prod"
          }
        ],
        "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {
          "name": "delete test",
          "description": "asdfasdf",
          "folderName": "Altigo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above call you made will not remove tabs, it will just update them.
You can remove a tab from a template using this call:

```
DELETE /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

Where the body has the JSON specifying which tabs to remove.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateRecipientTabs/delete